# How can you integrate planck's law to get Stefan-Bolzmann using python?

Tags: python, physics, sympy

I'm new to python and am trying to get the stefan boltzmann law by integrating analytically Plancks law. So far I plotted the black body radiation curves but I'm stuck on how to integrate it.This is my function:

```
import numpy as np
h=6.626e-34
c=3.0e+8
k=1.38e-23

def planck(x,T):
    a=2.0*h*c**2
    b=(h*c)/*x*k*T)
    intensity= a/( (x**5)*(np.exp(b)-1.0)
    return intensity
```

to integrate it i tried using  SymPy like this:

```
from sympy import *
x=Symbol('x')
T=Symbol('T')
integrate((x**3)/(exp(x)-1))
```

but it can't do the integration. I'm sure there is a simplification I'm supposed to do but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Please correct your `b=` line. How confident are you that a symbolic integral expression exists? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+x^3%2F%28exp%28x%29-1%29 uses some special functions, polylogarithms, that probably are not supported in sympy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get from Plancks law to the Stefan-Boltzmann law you need to integrate over all frequencies [(1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law). Thus you need a definite integral:

```
integrate((x**3)/(exp(x)-1),(x,0,oo))
```

The integration is detailed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?oldid=293273084#Appendix).
The Riemann zeta function can be used in sympy:

```
n = symbols('n')
riemann_zeta = functions.special.zeta_functions.zeta(n,1)
```

but of course there is no dependency on x anymore. Unfortunately sympy can not transform the integral to the analytic expression:

```
x = symbols('x', real=True, negative=False)
pprint(simplify(integrate((x**3)/(exp(x)-1),(x,0, oo))))
```

will just give $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^3}{e^x-1}dx$ and not $\zeta(4)\Gamma(4)=\frac{\pi^4}{15}$.
(Sorry about the LaTeX...)

Comment: I'm still kind of confused on how to use the riemann zeta function. do i have to import it from sympy first? and so i put that before i call the integration or after?

Comment: You can use the riemann zeta function as shown in answer, or try `functions.special.zeta_functions.zeta(4,1)`, but as I said before sympy can not transform the integral to the riemann zeta function nor evaluate the integral. The functionality simply seems to be not implemeted yet.

Comment: okay thank you. Do you know how to add a marker to the peaks of the curves? I tried using      'from scipy.signal import find_peaks_cwt '                                       and then 'indexes=find_peaks_cwt(intensity3000, np.arange(1e-9,3e-6))     plt.plot(indexes)'

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to add a marker at a specific position. I suggest differentiating your curve to find extremal values could help. Mixing sympy and scipy is usually difficult as they have a very different approach (and here I think there is no need for scipy, at least for "good" functions). If this does not help I recommend asking a new question and posting everything you have now, especially the curve you want to find the peaks for.